# How to use variables with string.replace()?

Tags: javascript, str-replace

I need to replace a lot of characters in a string. So I built two strings. One is called strSearch which contains all characters I want to replace. The other is strReplace which contains all the characters which would replace the respective characters of strSearch. It looks like this:

```
var strSearch="\n\t,.", strReplace="//T#!";
```

I would like to run a for loop which each character of strSearch and replace it with the character of the same index in strReplace. The issue is that string.replace() does not encapsulate the first argument in quotes, thereby making it impossible to pass variables in it.

I could manually create a string.replace() statement using eval() for each iteration of the loop, but I despise the idea of using eval().

Is there any other way I can pass variables for string.replace()?

Comment: this is a classic **regular expressions** situation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Are strSearch and strReplace always the same length?

Comment: Is it possible to make `strSearch` & `strReplace` arrays instead of strings?

Comment: @catgirlkelly yes. Always the same length. With precisely one character to replace one respective character.

Comment: @SSM yes. Definitely possible to convert those strings to arrays and use the respective members.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.prototype.replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) and replace all the characters in the `from` array with respective characters in the `to` array.

```js
const replaceChars = (str, from, to) =>
  Array.from(from).reduce((s, ch, i) => s.replaceAll(ch, to[i]), str);

console.log(replaceChars("mango", "ma", "bi"));
console.log(replaceChars("banana", "ab", "on"));
```